# Show repeated max value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
|   Student_Id   |  Student_Name  |  Assessment_Type | Mark  |
+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
|   300          |      John      |   Assignment     |  1    |
|   200          |      Liz       |    Final         |  2    |
|   300          |      John      |   Mid-term       |  3    |
|   100          |      Sue       |   Mid-term       |  4    |
|   200          |      Liz       |    Project       |  5    |
|   300          |      John      |   Assignment     |  6    |
|   200          |      Liz       |    Final         |  7    |
|   300          |      John      |   Mid-term       |  8    |
|   100          |      Sue       |   Mid-term       |  8    |
|   200          |      Liz       |    Project       |  9    |
+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
```

I would like to find the max mark grouped by Assessment_Type, and if there is a duplicate, show both, so in this case:

```
+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
|   Student_Id   |  Student_Name  |  Assessment_Type | Mark  |
+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
|   300          |      John      |   Assignment     |  6    |
|   200          |      Liz       |    Final         |  7    |
|   300          |      John      |   Mid-term       |  8    |
|   100          |      Sue       |   Mid-term       |  8    |
|   200          |      Liz       |    Project       |  9    |
+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
```

What I have only shows one of them:

```
SELECT Student_Id, Student_Name, Assessment_Type, max(mark) FROM STUDENT_ASSESSMENT group by Student_Id, Assessment_Type;
```

Edit: Added more details to question.

Comment: `GROUP BY Student_Id`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion in the question, in my original problem I am supposed to group by Assessment_Type as well, I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find max marks in each assessment type and then compare that max(marks) and assessment type with each row.

```
select * from STUDENTS_ASSESSMENT where (Assessment_Type,marks) in 
((select Assessment_Type,max(marks) from STUDENTS_ASSESSMENT groupby Assessment_Type));
```

Comment: Error on comma between `Assessment_Type` and `Marks`

Answer (score 0):

You could find maximum value of the `Mark` column, then select rows that `Mark` value is equal to this value:

```
SELECT 
  Student_Id, Student_Name, Assessment_Type, Mark
FROM
  STUDENT_ASSESSMENT FullSet
JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(Mark) AS Mark FROM STUDENT_ASSESSMENT) MaxMark
USING (Mark);
```